How to pass Powershell script error to Task Scheduler
I‘m running a Windows PC in an environment with quite some power failures. It therefore needs to send me an email every time it has rebooted.
I have implemented a task in the task scheduler that is triggered by system start.
This task executes a Powershell script that includes a „Send-MailMessage“ instruction.
This in principle works well e.g. after a Windows update triggered reboot. However if there is a power failure and the network infrastructure takes longer to recover than booting up the PC I don‘t get any email. Even I have set in the settings of my task scheduler task the switch that the task should be repeated every 5 minutes in case that it fails, I don‘t get any email.
My question is: how is the failure of an instruction like „Send-MailMessage“ within a Powershell script passed to the Task Scheduler that obviously not seem to start the task a second or third time.
If I run my script in a shell simulating that it can’t connect to the email server, e.g. by using a wrong smtp server address, the script exist with the usual failure messages. If I use this modified script in Task Scheduler, it shows after a reboot that the process was executed successfully.
What is the correct mechanism to pass an error on so that task scheduler knows that something went wrong and it would fire up a second or third try until the network is up again?

You need to start schedule task with RunAs with an account that has an associate email account.  Most likely the default account for schedule task is System which probably doesn't have an email account. You could create an email account for System.

What'd I'd do is program the script to test the network connection before attempting to send emails. Additionally, you can add a counter and have the script EXIT 1 if it fails to ping after 5 minutes. I'd imagine that'd make the scheduled task properly re-run as well.
do {
$ping = test-connection google.com -count 1 -Quiet
} until ($ping)
Send-Mail -Something

Is this what you wanted? I'll update my answer accordingly : )

Your other option would be to test whether the message had sent correctly within a Try Catch, and if it failed wait a while before retrying. For example :
try {
    Send-MailMessage -From $mailfrom -To $mailto -Subject $mailsubject -Body $mailbody -SmtpServer $mailserver -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    Write-Output "Error sending, retrying in 10 minutes"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 600
    Send-MailMessage -From $mailfrom -To $mailto -Subject $mailsubject -Body $mailbody -SmtpServer $mailserver -ErrorAction Stop
}

Where it catches the error, waits for 10 minutes and then re-tries to send the email, at which point assuming whatever hadn't previously started has now done so it will successfully send. And obviously as long as you ensure the email message body you're generating includes the time when the issue was seen, then when you receive it you'll be able to see that it was delayed.



What is the correct mechanism to pass an error on so that task scheduler knows that something went wrong and it would fire up a second or third try until the network is up again?

You need to communicate failure to the task scheduler via your PowerShell process' exit code.
To that end:

In the configuration of your scheduled task, invoke your PowerShell script via the the PowerShell CLI (powershell.exe for Windows PowerShell, pwsh for PowerShell (Core) 7), passing the full path to your .ps1 script to the -File parameter.

Inside your script, ensure that you terminate with an exit call to which you pass a nonzero number, e.g. exit 1

I'm unclear on whether the (now obsolete) Send-MailMessage cmdlet reports non-terminating or statement-terminating errors, but if you use the following idiom, both cases are covered:
try {
  Send-MailMessage -ErrorAction Stop ...  
} catch {
  # Send-MailMessage failed, exit with nonzero exit code.
  # (Possibly also log the specific error somewhere).
  exit 1
}





